# c# restful selfhosted api winforms works with my local ip but dosent work with my plubic ip event with port redirect

Tags: c#, winforms, api, rest

So the problem is this, I created a restful selfhosted api, to work with my mobile app, on the app mobile I stored my public ip (190.xxx.xxx.xxx) when I try to consume the api from the same network donset work no response, If I go 3g or in anoter network its work fine.

I try on my browser those 2 situation:

http://localIp:port/api/Menu/... its work

http://externalIp:port/api/Menu/... dont work - ps. this work only if I on a diferent network or 3g.

But I need to keep sotored my plubic IP for the external users and I dont want to store 2 ips internal and external to check if the user is on local network or external.

in summary my clients can use the app outside the office, but in the office with wifi connected they cant.

Tks for anyhelp

Answer (score 0):

I found this and solve my problem

https://docs.connectwise.com/ConnectWise_Control_Documentation/On-premises/On-premises_knowledge_base/Cannot_access_external_IP_address_from_LAN

Introduction
In some scenarios, a user cannot use an external IP address to access a machine on their local network. This is typically a result of security measures put in place by routers and referred to as a Network Address Translation (NAT) loopback issue. This article will discuss what this means for ConnectWise Control® on-premises users and will provide some suggestions.

What is NAT loopback?
Many routers and some security tools prevent loopback connections as a security feature. This means that a machine on your local network cannot connect to the external IP address (such as 208.112.93.73) of a machine that is also on your local network. Connecting to a local IP address (such as 192.168.0.2) of that same machine works fine.